# Where Munin plugins should be placed

Tags: linux, debian, plugins, munin

Debian places Munin plugins in `/usr/share/munin/plugins/` by default, and links the active ones from `/etc/munin/plugins/`.

Now I have a custom plugin and I'm not sure where to place it. I'm afraid that during a software upgrade, `apt` might automatically delete files in `/etc/munin/plugins/` and assume they can be recreated, as by default these are all just links. I'm also afraid that my plugin could be automatically deleted during and upgrade if I place it in `/usr/share/munin/plugins/`, as `apt` may assume that all files contained there are extracted from the Munin packages, and hence can be deleted and replaced by the updated package.

Best practices?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, files installed by package manager will be installed at `/usr`, `/bin`, etc. If you are installing something manually then you should place it under: `/usr/local`.

So in your case instead of using `/usr/share` you should use `/usr/local/share` to place your files, this path will be untouched by Debian package manager.

You can find more information using: `man hier` and by searching for `/usr/local`.